# Using a custom hook I am unable to refresh/re-render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using a custom hook that creates a LOAD MORE functionality:

```js
import React from 'react'

export const useLoadMore = (data, postsPerPage = 12) => {
  const [postsToShow, setPostsToShow] = React.useState([])
  const [next, setNext] = React.useState(postsPerPage)

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedPosts = data.slice(start, end)
    setPostsToShow([...postsToShow, ...slicedPosts])
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage)
  }, [])

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    loopWithSlice(next, next + postsPerPage)
    setNext(next + postsPerPage)
  }

  return { handleShowMorePosts, postsToShow }
}
```

Then I need to filter an array by price, when the filter is set the component should re-render but it is not doing it:

```js
const Comp = ({ data }) => {

    const [filterBy, setFilter] = useState(null)
    const [defaultData, setData] = useState(get(data, 'products', []))
    
    const handleFilters = () => {
        let sorted = defaultData
    
        if (filterBy === 'high') {
          sorted = defaultData.sort(({ variants: [firstVariant] }, { variants: [secondVariant] }) => {
            return parseFloat(secondVariant.price) - parseFloat(firstVariant.price)
          })
        }
    
        return sorted
    }
    
    const { handleShowMorePosts, postsToShow } = useLoadMore(defaultData)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setData(handleFilters())
    }, [filterBy, defaultData])
    
    return (<div>{postsToShow.map(...)}</div>)

}
```

That `handleFilters` function returns what I need `{price: "1250.00"}` that's the output for the higher price.

I have tried some different ways already and it doesn't seem to work even if I see the logs in the browser console, the component is not re-rendering.

It seems as if the `useLoadMore` hook is not setting the new array of data, it only grabs the initial of the array and sets it but it is not setting the new array when it changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that useLoadMore hook only triggers and sets data on mound an on handleShowMorePosts, it does not react when you change default data, I guess you should start pagination from 0 after filtering, right?

Comment: @BesoKakulia you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` can't detect an array changes so one way is to use `array.length` as dependency

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage, true)
    setNext(postsPerPage)

  }, [data.length])
```

But it is not reliable as if next filtered data will have same length it won't work.

Better I suggest add another parameter to `useLoadMore`,
`useLoadMore = (data, postsPerPage = 12, shouldReset)`
and reset load more depending on it

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage, true)
    setNext(postsPerPage)

  }, [shouldReset])
```

and use the filter by value as its arguments

```
 const { handleShowMorePosts, postsToShow } = useLoadMore(defaultData, 12, filterBy)
```

Also `JSON.stringify(data)` as dependency should work.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage, true)
    setNext(postsPerPage)

  }, [JSON.stringify(data)])
```

And prevent merging if it is the initial call

```
  const loopWithSlice = (start, end, shouldReset) => {
    const slicedPosts = data.slice(start, end)
    if(shouldReset) {
      setPostsToShow(slicedPosts)
     } else {
      setPostsToShow([...postsToShow, ...slicedPosts])
    }
```

Comment: With this code, it doesn't remove the first 12 items. It shows the new sorted items below the old-first items. So instead of only 12 items, it shows 24, 12 old, 12 sorted-new.

Comment: Every time I change the filter, it shows 12 new sorted items without removing the unsorted items.

Comment: @Reacting forget to reset the data check updated answer.

Comment: Don't know why but for some reason it is not working either :/

Comment: @Reacting issue was in resetting data `setPostsToShow([])` was overwritten in loopWithSlice as they were called in the same execution.